# Is it good to initialize collection properties

Tags: c#

Is it good to initialise collection properties?

for example, my class is,

```
 public class Part
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PartTypeId { get; set; }        
        public IList<Child> Instructions { get; set; }
 }
```

Is it a good idea to initialise Instructions like this?:

```
public IList<Child> Instructions { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
```

1. What is the best practice, default initialise or not initialise child collection properties?
2. Is it good to consider Lazy initialization?

Comment: I don't think so. Usually we initialize in constructor

Comment: @Deepak Kumar: That's unusual to me. Most code I've seen only initializes in the constructor what gets passed as constructor parameters.

Comment: I don't see why not... It's a feature that came with C# 6.0, it's super useful it saves you to do it from the constructor where you would do the same thing, but now it takes care of that out of the box. If you don't want the variable to be initialised at the time of creation of an instance of that class, then you leave it blank as usual and do it later.. so it is just a 'time-saver' trick.

Comment: More concerning is a publicly *settable* collection property. More often than not, that's a mistake (you want one collection under *your* class's control). And you don't want someone else to set it to `null`, surely?

Comment: @DeepakKumar This *does* initialise in the constructor: property or field initialisers are translated by the compiler to execute as part of the constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Well, if you don't initialize your collections, you won't be able to use them. If you're going to use a collection, might as well initialize it ASAP so you can just use it without worrying about a null reference.
2. Lazily initializing an empty collection isn't necessary. An empty collection doesn't take much work to initialize and doesn't take up much memory once initialized. Even if you don't end up populating it during the lifetime of your application, it's not going to have a measurable impact on performance.

   A *non-empty* collection is somewhat of a different story. If it's a small collection of primitive values, it probably isn't going to make much of a difference either. But if this will be a collection of large, complex objects that isn't required on launch, it may be wise to do it lazily. Whether you do that with a `new` in the property declaration and populating it separately, or `new`ing and populating it all at once on demand, is a matter of preference (and whether your application relies on the collection being there or not — most applications ask if the collection is populated or not instead, which brings us back to my point on empty collections).

As pointed out by Damien_The_Unbeliever, you probably don't want your collection property to be settable by anyone other than the class itself, if at all. All your collection operations will be performed on the collection itself without actually changing (or removing) the collection, so a setter is not required and should in fact be left out:

```
public IList<Child> Instructions { get; } = new List<Child>();
```